# How to get the position of a Windows Form on the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, position

I am coding a WinForms application in Visual Studio C# 2010 and I want to find out the location of the upper left corner of the WinForm window (the starting location of the window).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20):

If you are accessing it from within the form itself then you can write

```
int windowHeight = this.Height;
int windowWidth = this.Width;
```

to get the width and height of the window. And

```
int windowTop = this.Top; 
int windowLeft = this.Left;
```

To get the screen position.

Otherwise, if you launch the form and are accessing it from another form

```
int w, h, t, l;
using (Form form = new Form())
{
    form.Show();
    w = form.Width;
    h = form.Height;
    t = form.Top;
    l = form.Left;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 but maybe int should be type double. I'm using WPF not sure if it's different.

Answer (score 7):

`Form.Location.X` and `Form.Location.Y` will give you the X and Y coordinates of the top left corner.

Comment: there is a problem: when i type "Control." in the drop down menu that you will normally expect to drop down (after typing ".") there is no option to select "Location" what do i do? Do i have to include some "using" at the top of my code?

Comment: There are perhaps other spellings involved.  Try **form.DesktopBounds**, **form.DesktopLocation**, **form.Location**, **form.RestoreBounds**, **form.Size**, perhaps one of these others will give you the information you seek.  Also of note, the WinForms property list evolves as the version of .NET Framework evolves -- 4.5 has a richer list than 2.0.

Comment: But all that is about **Form**, if you want **Control** then the list of choices include: **control.Bounds**, **control.ClientRectangle**, **control.ClientSize**, **control.Location**, **control.Size**, or just **control.Left**, **control.Top**, **control.Width**, **control.Height**.  And since a **Form** is a **Control**, ....

Answer (score 6):

check this:
[Form.DesktopLocation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation?view=netframework-4.8)

```
        int left = this.DesktopLocation.X;
        int top = this.DesktopLocation.Y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Form.Bounds.Top` to get the "Y" coordinate and `Form.Bounds.Left` to get the "X" coordinate

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case where for my Form2 i needed the screen location of Form1. i Solved it by passing the screen locationof form1 to form2 through its constructor :

//Form1

```
 Point Form1Location;
        Form1Location = this.Location;
        Form2 myform2 = new Form2(Form1Location);
        myform2.Show();
```

//Form2

```
 Point Form1Loc;
    public Form2(Point Form1LocationRef)
    {
        Form1Loc = Form1LocationRef;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a combination of the Left and Top properties (e.g. this.Top from within the form)