# How to access form's location propertie?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, data-binding, properties

So I have class '`employee`' in which I have the properties `double X` and `double Y` and I want to bind these two to the form's location. (top left corner) I have tried to do it using [How to get the position of a Windows Form on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526101/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-windows-form-on-the-screen) 
but it only gives the value which is not helpful.

How can I access the actual properties?

So far have tried:

```
this.Left.DataBindings.Add("Value", EmpNd, "ThisEmployee.X", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
```

Comment: Please show your work first.

Comment: @Sach What should I show? I have a form and a class and in the class, there are x and y  properties that I want to bind to the form using the ```DataBindings.Add``` method.

Comment: So your code. Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Sach added what you wanted

Comment: You should create a MCVE, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two text boxes that will display `X` and `Y` coordinates of the form. In your form's `Load` event, you can bind the form's `DesktopLocation.X` and `DesktopLocation.Y` properties like so:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtX.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DesktopLocation.X, null);
    txtY.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DesktopLocation.Y, null);
}
```

If you want the text boxes to display the updated value as you move your form, you can declare a method that does this, and call it whenever `Form_Move()` event occurs:

```
private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDataBindings();
}

public void RefreshDataBindings()
{
    txtX.DataBindings.Clear();
    txtY.DataBindings.Clear();
    txtX.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DesktopLocation.X, null);
    txtY.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.DesktopLocation.Y, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you bind it with a class property?